# group check box in php and send to email

Tags: php

I am using a sample php conatct form from http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/php-contact-form-tutorial.html and I want to use check box in my form , but I am receiving only last checked one in my email. I find out that I should use array for check boxes like:

```
input type="checkbox" name="chk_group[]" value="value1" />Value 1<br />
input type="checkbox" name="chk_group[]" value="value2" />Value 2<br />
input type="checkbox" name="chk_group[]" value="value3" />Value 3<br />
```

and I should use following loop some where in my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['chk_group'])) {
    $optionArray = $_POST['chk_group'];
    for ($i=0; $i'<'count($optionArray); $i++) {
        echo $optionArray[$i]."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Unfortunately I tried but because the sample contact form which I am using is a little bit strange for me I got errors.

I appreciate if some one can help me to solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: `'<'` is not a string, it is an operator.  No quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes around `<`. It should be:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($optionArray); $i++) {
```

You may also replace the `for` loop with a [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) loop:

```
foreach($optionArray as $element) {
    echo $element."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Hi : where should I use this loop in my code? because I am using the sample , it has a include file which has fgcontact file and php mailer, I got confused

Comment: Either remove the quotes around "<", or replace the `for` loop with the `foreach` loop I posted. My code is based on the code you posted.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. if you saw the template that I am using is from this site: http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/php-contact-form-tutorial.html , this sample has a folder called include which has fgcontact and php mailer, should I put this loop in one of these flies or I should directly insert into top of my php contact page which my conatct form is writtern ?